# how to fill blank spaces in flex box in html

Tags: html, css

How do I fill the gap using CSS where boxes take up blank spaces automatically? Each box could be of different size. How do I fit boxes automatically as screen size changes?

```css
.c1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#i1 {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="c1">
    <div id="i1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="a"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a solution using the height of the container. It is necessary to use the required number of items so that they fit exactly in the columns. But this solution does not cause any space inside the container.

[image]

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-big-item{
  background-color: cornflowerblue !important;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item flex-big-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-big-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-big-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div><div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's invalid to reuse ID values. They must be unique. I'd refactor to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about flex, but there is no solution for this using flex, so my snippet below is just a solution under certain cirumstances: If the "double-heigth" elements only appear at the very left (i.e. in situations where the number of elements per line will *not* change), you can simply use `float:left` on all child elements of your container.

```css
.c1 * {
  float: left;
}

#i1 {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="c1">
    <div id="i1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="a"></div>

</body>
```